image and buttons not being displayed in popup window
i used a previous version on this project since the latest on got corrupted due to unknown reasons.

it was working perfectly fine before but suddenly an encoding error appeared and i decided to reinstall python and all the modules but then i couldnt open the customer screen and the buttons dont appear as well

import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
 
def CustomerScreen():
    def Page1():
        root = tk.Tk() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("StarFinity Telescope | See the World Through a new Perspective")
        root['background'] = 'white'
        tk.Label(root, text ="Explore By Models",bg="white",fg="black",font = ("Verdana", 20)).pack()
        C = Canvas(root, bg ="white", height = 250, width = 300)
        load=Image.open("model1.png")
        img3=ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        label1=tk.Label(root,image=img3)
        label1.image=img3
        label1.place(x=0,y=0)
        label1.pack()
        root.mainloop()
    
        
        
    def Page2():
        root = tk.Tk() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("Luxury Sedans, SUVs, Electric Vehicles & More | Audi Dubai | Audi Middle East")
        root['background'] = '#F8F6F0'
        tk.Label(root, text ="LIST OF VEHICLES",bg="#F8F6F0",fg="#e82127",font = ("OCR A Extended", 20)).pack()
        
        
    def Page3():
        root = tk.Tk() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("Luxury Sedans, SUVs, Electric Vehicles & More | Audi Dubai | Audi Middle East")
        root['background'] = '#F8F6F0'
        tk.Label(root, text ="LIST OF VEHICLES",bg="#F8F6F0",fg="#e82127",font = ("OCR A Extended", 20)).pack()
        
    def Page4():
        root = tk.Tk() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("Luxury Sedans, SUVs, Electric Vehicles & More | Audi Dubai | Audi Middle East")
        root['background'] = '#F8F6F0'
        tk.Label(root, text ="LIST OF VEHICLES",bg="#F8F6F0",fg="#e82127",font = ("OCR A Extended", 20)).pack()
    
    def Page5():
        root = tk.Tk() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("Luxury Sedans, SUVs, Electric Vehicles & More | Audi Dubai | Audi Middle East")
        root['background'] = '#F8F6F0'
        tk.Label(root, text ="LIST OF VEHICLES",bg="#F8F6F0",fg="#e82127",font = ("OCR A Extended", 20)).pack()
        
       
    root = tk.Tk() 
    root.geometry("1000x562") 
    root.title("Login Page")
    root.configure(bg="white")
    C = Canvas(root, bg ="white", height = 250, width = 300)
    img1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("mountainmorning.jpg"))
    label=Label(root,image=img1)
    label.place(x=0,y=0)
    btnpg1 = tk.Button(root, text ="Page 1",fg ='white',bg= 'black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10),command = Page1) 
    btnpg1.place(x = 1075, y = 250, width = 60)
    btnpg2 = tk.Button(root, text ="Page 2",fg ='white',bg= 'black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10),command = Page2) 
    btnpg2.place(x = 1075, y = 300, width = 60)
    btnpg3 = tk.Button(root, text ="Page 3",fg ='white',bg= 'black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10),command = Page5) 
    btnpg3.place(x = 1075, y = 350, width = 60)
    btnpg4 = tk.Button(root, text ="Page 4",fg ='white',bg= 'black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10),command = Page5) 
    btnpg4.place(x = 1075, y = 400, width = 60)
    btnpg5 = tk.Button(root, text ="Page 4",fg ='white',bg= 'black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10),command = Page5) 
    btnpg5.place(x = 1075, y = 450, width = 60)
    lblname = tk.Label(root, text ="The art of engineering.",bg= 'black',fg ='white',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18) ) 
    lblname.place(x = 400, y = 470)
    
    
    root.mainloop()
def loginscreen():
    def clear():
        txtUser.delete(0,END)
        txtpass.delete(0,END)
        txtUser.focus()

    def login():     
        user = txtUser.get() 
        password = txtpass.get()
        if user in alog.keys():
            if password ==alog[user]:
                messagebox.showinfo("Admin Login", "Login Successful. Welcome Back, Sir!")
                root.destroy() 
                AdminScreen()
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("Login ", "Login Denied. Please Check Login Details Again.")
        
        
        elif user in log.keys():
            if password==log[user]:
                messagebox.showinfo("Login ", "Login Successful. Welcome Back!")
                root.destroy()
                CustomerScreen()
                
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("Login ", "Login Denied. Please Check Login Details Again.")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Login ", "Login Denied. Please Check Login Details Again.")
    def signup():
        user=txtUser.get()
        password=txtpass.get()
        if user in log.keys():
            messagebox.showinfo("","this account already exists. please login to your account")
        else:
            op1=messagebox.askquestion("","Are you sure that you want this to be your LoginID and Password?")
            if op1 =="yes":
                op2=messagebox.askquestion("","Are you a 101% sure?")
                if  op2=="yes":
                    log[user]=password      
    from PIL import ImageTk,Image    
    root = tk.Tk() 
    root.geometry("1000x565") 
    root.title("Login Page")
    root.configure(bg="white")
    C = Canvas(root, bg ="white", height = 250, width = 300)
    img3=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image.jpg"))
    label=Label(root,image=img3)
    label.place(x=0,y=-10)
    
    lbllogin = tk.Label(root, text ="LoginID",fg="Black",bg="white",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18) ) 
    lbllogin.place(x = 680, y = 250) 
    txtUser = tk.Entry(root, width = 35,fg="Black",bg="white",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10)) 
    txtUser.place(x = 830 , y = 250, width = 150) 
    lblpass = tk.Label(root, text ="Password",fg="Black",bg="white",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18)) 
    lblpass.place(x = 680 , y = 325) 
    txtpass = tk.Entry(root,show="*", width = 35,fg="blue",bg="white",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10)) 
    txtpass.place(x = 830, y = 325, width = 150) 
    loginbtn = tk.Button(root, text ="Login", fg ='black', font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18),command = login) 
    loginbtn.place(x = 690, y = 450, width = 100)
    clearbtn = tk.Button(root, text ="Clear",fg ='black', font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18),command = clear) 
    clearbtn.place(x = 890, y = 450, width = 100)
    signupbtn = tk.Button(root, text ="Sign Up",fg ='black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18),command=signup) 
    signupbtn.place(x = 790, y = 450, width = 100)
    root.mainloop()



the error in am getting
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ypgnv\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ypgnv\Desktop\telescope\telescope.py", line 340, in login
    CustomerScreen()
  File "C:\Users\ypgnv\Desktop\telescope\telescope.py", line 120, in CustomerScreen
    img1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("mountainmorning.jpg"))
  File "C:\Users\ypgnv\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.paste(image)
  File "C:\Users\ypgnv\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 175, in paste
    im.load()
  File "C:\Users\ypgnv\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 312, in load
    raise _get_oserror(err_code, encoder=False)
OSError: broken data stream when reading image file

i decided to reinstall python and all the modules but then i couldnt open the customer screen and the buttons dont appear as well

The file mountainmorning.jpg appears to be corrupted - can you view it with other software?  Also, all of those calls to Tk() are going to cause problems - that's something that should be done once per program, use Toplevel() to create additional windows.

Use only one mainloop() at the end, and the rest will be deleted.

the file image seems perfectly fine as it appears when i use photos on my laptop, but i will try using Toplevel()

You have to think of each instance of Tk as it's own environment. Images and widgets created in one aren't available in any others. And by default, images are always created in the very first instance of Tk.

This question OSError: broken data stream when reading image file may help.

Cannot reproduce the issue when adding back missing alog and log variables, using my sample images and execute loginscreen() at the end of the code.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Edit: I deleted my answer. I did not see the other widgets, such as login, entry, etc.

image and buttons not being displayed in popup window

The problem can be fixed.
I removed all duplicates.

Move the root = tk.Tk() before CustomerScreen() function.
Use one Tk() and mainloop() for the entire script.
To open a new window, use tk.Toplevel().
Do not use both layout, simulate place(), and pack().
Change this x = 1075, y = 250 to x = 15, y = 320. Change y to every
30 steps.
Move the loginscreen() outside of CustomerScreen().
Add this CustomerScreen() and loginscreen() to the end.

You ready to go.
Here is the rewritten script:
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.font as font
#from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = tk.Tk()

def CustomerScreen():
             
    def Page1():
        root = tk.Toplevel() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("StarFinity Telescope | See the World Through a new Perspective")
        root['background'] = 'white'
        tk.Label(root, text ="Explore By Models",bg="white",fg="black",font = ("Verdana", 20)).pack()
        C = Canvas(root, bg ="white", height = 250, width = 300)
        load=Image.open("p1.png")
        img3=ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        label1=tk.Label(root,image=img3)
        label1.image=img3
        label1.place(x=0,y=0)
                   
        
    def Page2():
        root = tk.Toplevel() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("Luxury Sedans, SUVs, Electric Vehicles & More | Audi Dubai | Audi Middle East")
        root['background'] = '#F8F6F0'
        tk.Label(root, text ="LIST OF VEHICLES",bg="#F8F6F0",fg="#e82127",font = ("OCR A Extended", 20)).pack()
        
        
    def Page3():
        root = tk.Toplevel() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("Luxury Sedans, SUVs, Electric Vehicles & More | Audi Dubai | Audi Middle East")
        root['background'] = '#F8F6F0'
        tk.Label(root, text ="LIST OF VEHICLES",bg="#F8F6F0",fg="#e82127",font = ("OCR A Extended", 20)).pack()
        
    def Page4():
        root = tk.Toplevel() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("Luxury Sedans, SUVs, Electric Vehicles & More | Audi Dubai | Audi Middle East")
        root['background'] = '#F8F6F0'
        tk.Label(root, text ="LIST OF VEHICLES",bg="#F8F6F0",fg="#e82127",font = ("OCR A Extended", 20)).pack()

    def Page5():
        root = tk.Toplevel() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("Luxury Sedans, SUVs, Electric Vehicles & More | Audi Dubai | Audi Middle East")
        root['background'] = '#F8F6F0'
        tk.Label(root, text ="LIST OF VEHICLES",bg="#F8F6F0",fg="#e82127",font = ("OCR A Extended", 20)).pack()
            
    root.geometry("1000x562") 
    root.title("Login Page")
    root.configure(bg="white")
    C = Canvas(root, bg ="white", height = 250, width = 300)
    img1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p2.png"))
    label=Label(root,image=img1)
    label.image=img1
    label.place(x=0,y=0)

    btnpg1 = tk.Button(root, text ="Page 1",fg ='white',bg= 'black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10), command=Page1) 
    btnpg1.place(x = 15, y = 320, width = 60)
    btnpg2 = tk.Button(root, text ="Page 2",fg ='white',bg= 'black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10), command=Page2) 
    btnpg2.place(x = 15, y = 350, width = 60)
    btnpg3 = tk.Button(root, text ="Page 3",fg ='white',bg= 'black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10), command=Page3) 
    btnpg3.place(x = 15, y = 380, width = 60)
    btnpg4 = tk.Button(root, text ="Page 4",fg ='white',bg= 'black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10), command=Page4) 
    btnpg4.place(x = 15, y = 410, width = 60)
    btnpg5 = tk.Button(root, text ="Page 4",fg ='white',bg= 'black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10), command=Page5) 
    btnpg5.place(x = 15, y = 440, width = 60)
    lblname = tk.Label(root, text ="The art of engineering.",bg= 'black',fg ='white',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18) ) 
    lblname.place(x = 400, y = 470)
        
     
         
def loginscreen():
    def clear():
        txtUser.delete(0,END)
        txtpass.delete(0,END)
        txtUser.focus()

    def login():     
        user = txtUser.get() 
        password = txtpass.get()
        if user in alog.keys():
            if password ==alog[user]:
                messagebox.showinfo("Admin Login", "Login Successful. Welcome Back, Sir!")
                root.destroy() 
                AdminScreen()
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("Login ", "Login Denied. Please Check Login Details Again.")
        
        
        elif user in log.keys():
            if password==log[user]:
                messagebox.showinfo("Login ", "Login Successful. Welcome Back!")
                root.destroy()
                CustomerScreen()
                
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("Login ", "Login Denied. Please Check Login Details Again.")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Login ", "Login Denied. Please Check Login Details Again.")
    def signup():
        user=txtUser.get()
        password=txtpass.get()
        if user in log.keys():
            messagebox.showinfo("","this account already exists. please login to your account")
        else:
            op1=messagebox.askquestion("","Are you sure that you want this to be your LoginID and Password?")
            if op1 =="yes":
                op2=messagebox.askquestion("","Are you a 101% sure?")
                if  op2=="yes":
                    log[user]=password


    lbllogin = tk.Label(root, text ="LoginID",fg="Black",bg="white",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18) ) 
    lbllogin.place(x = 680, y = 250) 
    txtUser = tk.Entry(root, width = 35,fg="Black",bg="white",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10)) 
    txtUser.place(x = 830 , y = 250, width = 150) 
    lblpass = tk.Label(root, text ="Password",fg="Black",bg="white",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18)) 
    lblpass.place(x = 680 , y = 325) 
    txtpass = tk.Entry(root,show="*", width = 35,fg="blue",bg="white",font=("Times New Roman Bold", 10)) 
    txtpass.place(x = 830, y = 325, width = 150) 
                   
    loginbtn = tk.Button(root, text ="Login", fg ='black', font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18),command = login) 
    loginbtn.place(x = 690, y = 450, width = 100)

    clearbtn = tk.Button(root, text ="Clear",fg ='black', font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18),command = clear) 
    clearbtn.place(x = 890, y = 450, width = 100)
    signupbtn = tk.Button(root, text ="Sign Up",fg ='black',font=("Times New Roman Bold", 18),command=signup) 
    signupbtn.place(x = 790, y = 450, width = 100)         
 
    root.mainloop()

CustomerScreen()
loginscreen()

Screenshot:

Press page 1 button:

Press the same button as 2, 3, 4, and 5:

